# Adding close button to auto pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add an auto pop up box to the home page of a site. I have used the code from a previous answer on this site and as is follows below. The pop up works just fine but can you also add a close button/link to it? Thanks in advance for the help.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_popup()
{
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block'; 
}

window.onload = show_popup;
</script>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#popup
{
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
display:block;
top:200px;
left:50%;
width:567px;
height:420px; 
margin-left:-250px; 
}
```

**and the call:**

```
<div id="popup">pop up window</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>‌    
<div id="popup">
<div id='popup-close'>Close</div>
pop up window
</div>
```

And your jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#popup').show('fast'); // This will show the Pop Up in the Page Load
    $('#popup-close').click(function(e) // You are clicking the close button
    {
      $('#popup').hide('fast'); // Now the pop up is hided.
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you included the jQuery library just before this? If not include that. `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: I think I'm screwing something up somewhere. So here's what I've done. I've added in the extra script to the javascript:

    `code`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function show_popup()
    {
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block'; 
    }
    window.onload = show_popup;
    $('#popupclose').click(function(e)
    {
    $('#popup').hide('fast');
    });
    </script>`code`

and have used the div calls as provided but still no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have edited my answer. And I have posted the complete code which will be easy for you to understand.

Comment: If you still find anything difficult check this for demo http://jsfiddle.net/gDdAZ/

Answer (score 0):

Add another div into the `popup` that when clicked activates this `document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';`. You can `relatively` position the div to the `top, right` simple enough.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice with this, how would I activate the call? I mean, once the link is clicked to close the window, what will the call look like? <a href="insert call here..."> or something else?

Comment: if you're not using jQuery you can use the onclick() event tied to the div. eg: `<div id='popup-close' onclick='close_popup()'>Close</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using a 2nd positioned absolute div within your popup div.

Lot's of ways to improve on it and add more stuff.

```js
function show_popup() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block'; 
}
window.onload = show_popup;
$('.popup-closer').click(function() {
 $('#popup').hide();
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  top: 50%; left: 50%; /* if you want to center it do this.. */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* ..and this */
  width:150px;
  height:225px; 
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.popup-closer {
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup-closer:hover {
  background-color: white;
}




html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  pop up window
  <div class="popup-closer"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
</div>
```

If you want it only shown once per user per session or day look into session and local storage. The popup can first check their session storage if they've been served the notice already this session/this day/etc and if so prevent them being shown a 2nd+ time. Same deal if you have the code sitewide and you don't want it popping up every page load.

Also, may want to make #popup `position: fixed;` so when user scrolls page the popup stays with them until they acknowledge and close it.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/au3xm1oy/

and additional fiddle for more ideas

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/au3xm1oy/2/